# Android App Cashing on clicking advertsiment integrated on app via FireBase Admob

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I have integrated google Admob and Firebase SDK in Android app. And the Ad is showing correctly with impressions shown in the Admob and Firebase consoles.

But upon clicking any of the Ads from the app, the app CRASHES.

Following are the build details

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:21.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:17.4.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.7'
```

with build config

```
    ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=29
    ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=29.0.3
    ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=29
    ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=16
```

And this is the stack trace.

```
2020-07-02 01:19:01.819 28965-28965/in.typecast.scan10 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: in.typecast.scan10, PID: 28965
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.typecast.scan10/com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter bundle
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3448)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter bundle
        at in.typecast.utils.ApplicationLifecycleManager.onActivityCreated(Unknown Source:7)
        at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityCreated(Application.java:392)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityCreated(Activity.java:1232)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:1513)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity.onCreate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.2.0:2)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068) 
2020-07-02 01:19:02.193 28965-28965/in.typecast.scan10 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 28965 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Is `in.typecast.utils.ApplicationLifecycleManager.onActivityCreated` your code? That's where it is crashing

Comment: Thanks for the headsup @ianhanniballake. Yes the code is mine and it was the problem. Java-> kotlin conversion dint make the arguments nullable. 

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to my code. The ApplicationLifecycleManager method params were not defined nullable.

Answer (score 0):

The crash says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter bundle
    at in.typecast.utils.ApplicationLifecycleManager.onActivityCreated
```

Which means you've declared your parameter bundle as `bundle: Bundle` - it should be `bundle: Bundle?` - i.e., a nullable Bundle.